# Finding $f_{X|X>1}(x)$

Tags: probability

Given that $X\sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$, find $f_{X|X>1}(x)$.

I'm not familiar with random variables that condition on itself.
How would I start this?
I know that

$$f_{X|X}(x) = \frac{f_{X,X}(x,x)}{f_{X}(x)}
$$
How would I find the numerator here?

Comment: The formula you suggest is quite wrong, even absurd. Simply the definitions yield instead $$f_{X\mid X>1}(x)=\frac{f_X(x)}{P(X>1)}\mathbf 1_{x>1}$$

Comment: How did you get that (the numerator)?  
I was using $ f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}$. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Actually, I'm unsure how you got the denominator too (1 - F(x))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the following [note](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m60s06/public_html/Lecture12.pdf):

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with density function $f(x)$, and if $E$ is an event with positive probability, we define a conditional density function by the formula:

$$f(x|E) = \begin{cases} \frac{f(x)}{P(E)} & \text{if } x \in E \\ 0 & \text{if } x \notin E\end{cases}$$
Hence,
$$f_{X|X>1}(x)= \frac{f(x)}{P(X>1)}\bf{1} _{x>1} $$

Answer (score 0):

To me the best way to go through this kind of problem is to compute the expectation against a test function. Take a test function $\phi$, let us say bounded and continuous from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and compute
$$ \mathbb{E}[\phi(X)| X > 1] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[\phi(X) \mathbf{1}_{X>1}]}{\mathbb{P}(X > 1)},$$ 
this equality coming from the definition of conditional expectation for partition. Now if you just look at the density it gives you for this new variable, i.e. you look for $g$ such that 
$$ \mathbb{E}[\phi(X)|X > 1] = \int \phi(t) g(t) dt $$
you will find that $g$ is exactly as announced above.

Comment: The OP is not after a conditional expectation but more conditional PDF.